# Single In House Provisioning Profile - Distribute Multiple iOS Applications

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2013, ios-provisioning, airwatch

I am using Xamarin and Visual Studio to build several internal corporate applications.

I have an In House Provisioning Profile that I used to build and distribute one application using AirWatch.  Created the .ipa, signed it correctly, configured AirWatch distribution and everything worked fine.

Even made changes and created an updated version with no problems.

Now I want to use the same In House Provisioning for a different iOS application.

I build and sign it with no problem, but when I go into AirWatch to add the .ipa file, I get an error that the App ID already exists.

The App has a different name and version, but the Provisioning Profile is the same.

I thought the Provisioning Profile was generic and I was allowed to use it to bundle multiple Applications.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  Not much feedback from AirWatch to tell me what to do.

Comment: does it have a different bundle id?

Comment: My guess is that the bundle is you are using is the same between the two apps. App name and version don't matter. It's the bundle is that needs to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to reuse the same provisioning profiles, make sure that:

- You created a wildcard App ID
- Create a provisioning profiles using the wildcard App ID

If you already done that, then might be AirWatch does not allow 2 apps with the same App/bundle ID. 
You can create another AirWatch account for this new app or use other distribution tools like [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/).